# I can't enter on sda2

Tags: mount, directory, drive

This is probably going to be a stupid question, but still...
To learn Linux and broaden my horizons, I installed Ubuntu Server on a separate PC.
When I run the `df` command, I see that I have (among other things) a tom (or drive) sda2 (non-bootable) on which I would like to create a folder and experiment with sharing, permissions, etc.

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs             803320     2900    800420   1% /run
/dev/sda2      113709260 13214796  94672208  13% /
tmpfs            4016584        0   4016584   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda1        1098628     5364   1093264   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs             803316        4    803312   1% /run/user/1000
```

However, when I try to go to sda2, the terminal gives me an error message "`-bash: cd: /dev/sda2: Not a directory`".
When trying to mount sda2 somewhere - the message "`/dev/sda2 already mounted on /`".
When trying to create a folder with the command "`mkdir /dev/sda2/test`" - the message "cannot create directory "`mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/dev/sda2/test’: Not a directory`".
I did not find answers in Google (more precisely, I found only hints that I need to mount something).
Tell me, please, how can I create a folder exactly on sda2 in order to be able to work with it (enter, add files, share, etc.)?

p.s. I understand that now there will probably be a lot of mockery at my inexperience, however, I myself can’t cope yet.

Comment: sda2 is literally just your main hard drive (mounted on `/` means it's your root device) https://superuser.com/questions/558156/what-does-dev-sda-in-linux-mean

Comment: Thanks for link! Hm, ok. sda2 is one of the sda disk partitions.
I understood this earlier, but following the "logic of Windows" (which is of course wrong, but I can't explain otherwise) - if I want to create a folder and files on the sda2 disk (so as not to take up the capacity of the sda1 boot disk), then what's next? ..
Isn't it wrong to create a "docs/test/share" folder in the root "/" or "/dev" directory?
Whose conditional free capacity of two logical drives will decrease if a folder is created in the root directory? sda1 or sda2?

Comment: sda1 is *not* the boot disk, it is your EFI partition. sda2 is your root partition, and it is mounted at `/`, so to put things in that disk you put them in `/`.

Comment: if you put things in *any* directory in your system (except for /boot/efi), it will take capacity from /dev/sda2.

Comment: And you should usually put things in your home folder (`/home/<your_username>`) unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: Wow! Now I understood!
Many thanks for your detailed answer and clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `/dev/sda2` is mounted at `/` so if you want to change to that directory, use:

```
cd /
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!